# using a WPF custom control in Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, interop

I am making a wpf custom control in Winforms. I am using an element host to  embedded the wpf control in to my  Winforms.

I have a few different ellipses in my wpf custom control and they all have a mouse down event handler, and in run time went i click on a ellipses, I can change their color ,  but my question is how do I seen that information to my winform application from my wpf?

I tried this :

```
private void elementHost1_ChildChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ChildChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int stop =0;
    }
  private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse EP = sender as Ellipse;
        string tempS = EP.Name;
        EP.Fill = Brushes.Green;

        int you = 0;
    }
}
```

Also, event if the handler is called , I am not sure how to learn which  Ellipse called it 
also,
would there be a way of changing the  Ellipse color from the Winform ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use events to do that. Create an event for your wpf control and raise it when clicked, then in winform add handler to that event and listen to the event.

for creating event:

```
public event Action OnEllipseClick;
```

for raising it:

```
this.OnEllipseClick?.Invoke();
```

if winform for binding to event:

```
this.userControl11.OnEllipseClick += UserControl11_OnEllipseClick;

private void UserControl11_OnEllipseClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
}
```